# How to use existing javascript files in typescript files?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have existing project in nodejs + express in javascript. Currently everything is working on es5.

Now i added typescript in same project and i want to do all the new development in typescript. But i am facing a issue in accessing existing javascript files.

I found that i can create definition file xx.d.ts (not sure if it is correct approach) of each existing javascript file and then use it in typescript files.

For example i have javscript file

myFile.js

```
function myClass(){
//some functions here associated with this variable
}

exports.myData = new myClass();
```

now i want to use it in my new ts file

So what i did in ts file to access is

```
declare function require(path: string): any;

var auth = require('./myFile').myData;
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach. Secondly i tried with myFile.d.ts file as well.

I defined this file in following way

```
declare module './myFile' {
  export var myData: any
}
```

But this gives error of relative path - 
**TS2436 ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module path**

Please let me know if anybody has any idea to resolve this problem or suggest if it is okay to go with first approach.

Comment: Have you try `allowJS` option in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen is a great tool to generate declaration files.

Comment: @unional Thanks for the suggestion, I tried with that. But it gives different error regarding replacing exisiting file. ---- error TS5055: Cannot write file 'xx.js' because it would overwrite input file.

There is one solution for this problem is to have different destination folder but i dont want that .

Comment: @SiamandMaroufi I tried with this but it generate worst xx.d.ts files. It just write one line of code with export word. like - 

export 'path/xx.js"'

This npm package is basically used to generate definition file of npm packages which has ts file. It will not work with js file.

Comment: How do you manage your source control without a different destination folder?

Comment: @unional, my project was in pure javascript and node js so why do i need a different destination folder. Same source code folder can be deployed on server. I haven't faced any problem in that. Is there something wrong in keeping same folder for deployment? Do i need to have different folder for actual deployment code?

Comment: how do you commit your folder with both hand-written js files and generated js file from ts? You should commit ts files but not the compiled js and d.ts, right?

Comment: @unional Actually i just started writing ts files so not sure if i need to commit all the files or just ts files. Whats the problem to commit all the files inlcuding xx.d.ts and xx.s with ts files?

Comment: You won't commit the generated js and d.ts files just as if you write your js in ES6 and transpiled it to ES5 using babel. You will commit the ES6 code but not the generated ES5 code.

In the same sense, you typically mix source (ts) files with result (js) files.

Comment: @unional I think you are right. How could i commit compiled files. Its should not be done. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @unional I will try to create a destination file and will include allowJs flag. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution long back but didnt posted here. Let me add the answer here so that it can help everyone

Make changes in tsconfig.json. Most important part here is types and typeRoots properties

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": [ "es2015","dom" ]
  }
}
```

Now go to you package.json and add some type definition packages on the basis of need

```
 "@types/node": "~8.0.54",
```

After this configuration, nobody will get error and we dont need to separately specify declaration in each file

Comment: This answer is not related to the problem posted in the question